# Attach a file to a PDF using client-side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file, pdf, attachment

How can an arbitrary file (eg a XLSX) be attached/embedded to a PDF file using only client-side browser JavaScript?

If it matters, the XLSX is given by the user using a input file button and the PDF received from an external web service and encoded in base64.

I am not looking for a complete solution (it would be great if it exists), but how would you approach this problem in a higher level way

Files are attached using binary file streams, that looks like this in the PDF file:

```
32 0 obj
 <</Type /EmbeddedFile /Subtype /{mimetype} /Length 72>>
 stream
 {file data}
 endstream
 endobj
```

Comment: Is the PDF being viewed at the time?

Comment: The file should be attached to the pdf before displaying the pdf to the user.

Comment: What are you hoping to do with the xlsx? Like what would a successful solution do?

Comment: @Victor, if you are satisfied with my answer below, please mark it as accepted on the left side from my answer and / or upvote it.

Comment: @Bharata yes, you are right. Im sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use **[JSPdf library](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)** for this case. You have to took at **[JavaScript plugin](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/src/modules/javascript.js)** and at **[addImage plugin](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/src/modules/addimage.js)** source codes of this library to see how a file attachment could be done. I think that the JavaScript plugin source code is more understandable for this case.

> I am not looking for a complete solution

Yes, a complete solution you have to write by yourself because now this library does not support a custom file attachment.

> Files are attached using binary file streams, that looks like this in the PDF file:
>
> ```
> 32 0 obj
> <</Type /EmbeddedFile /Subtype /{mimetype} /Length 72>>
> stream
> {file data}
> endstream
> endobj
> ```

Yes, some like this you have to write. You have to realize that you have to write a code for reading from a PDF file too.

**Alternative solution**

But, if it is too difficult or too much work for you then you have to think about doing of all this on the server side. You could send to your server a request using AJAX and the server do it and gives you a new PDF back.

In this case you could edit a PDF server side with free PHP library like **[FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about)** for example. With FPDI it is possible to read and to edit PDF documents (use `createByFile()` method to read a PDF). The FPDI is extended version of **[FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org)** library, which has the **[plugin for attachments](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script95.php)**.